# How to disable validation as required field Billing Period Unit in magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8

hi guys when i edit any product from admin panel of magento there is require field Billing Period Unit.i want to keep no any such type of validation kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to your admin panel.
2. Go to c`atalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes`.
3. Manage the attribute which you don't want to have a require field
   and make the **values required** field option to **No**.

**This will definitely help you. Happy learning**

Comment: Thanks for reply but save  Manage Attributes is not working in my case can it be accomplish from another way

Comment: Save attribute is not working please  help me